# Playhaven HTTP error= "403 Forbidden" response= "invalid signature";}

Tags: http-status-code-403, xcode7.2, playhaven

I am a newby who purchased a reskin app and I'm having problems when trying to get the ads to pop up while in Xcode 7 testing on my iphone. I followed the steps to enter the token and secret ID codes after registering the app in playhaven but I keep getting the below error when running the test on Xcode in the debug area.
Stackoverflow is my last resort as the guy who sold me the app can't help...

Playhaven-1.24.0 Request received HTTP response: 403
Playhaven-1.24.0 Request finished
Playhaven-1.24.0 Server response 
errorbj - null
error - 403 Forbidden
response - invalid signature

I have tried the new SDK but get more errors/bugs

Please help me

Thanks so much
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Seems like playhavens end doesnt communicate with my account and token codes etc, same with Startapp!